# Prove that $\bar{h}:Y\to Z$ is a continuous function.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I've run into this rather tricky question (to me at least).

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be another set and let $f:X \to Y$ be a surjective function, and equip $Y$ with the quotient topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$.
Let $(Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$ be another topological space a let $h: X\to Z$ be a continuous function such that whenever $x_1,x_2\in X$ are such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$. For every $y\in Y$ choose $x_y\in X$ such that $f(x_y)=y$ (possible by surjectivity). Define the function $\bar{h}:Y\to Z$ as follows: for every $y\in Y$ put $\bar{h}(y):=h(x_y)$.
Prove that $\bar{h}:Y\to Z$ is a continuous function.

I'm pretty lost on this and have no idea where to start, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A subset $A\subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: So if I take an open subset $U\subseteq Z$ then by continuity of $h$, $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ and $f(h^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$. Is this useful ?

Comment: You know that $h=\bar{h}\circ f$ by construction. So, for $U$ open in $Z$ you have $f^{-1}(\bar{h}^{-1}(U))=h^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Ahh, and since $h^{-1}(U)$ is open by the definition of continuity the result follows. Thank you!

Comment: But, is $f$ continuous by hypothesis?

Comment: @Berci, $Y$ has the quotient topology induced by $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient topology on $Y$ is defined by declaring that $B\subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$.

By definition, we have $\bar{h}\circ f=h$ (check it); thus, if $U$ is open in $Z$,
$$
h^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(\bar{h}^{-1}(U))
$$
is open in $X$, which implies that $\bar{h}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$.